# Implementing thread-safe persistence using closures

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I have a Java class responsible for the interaction with the database, and several objects, which will concurrently access it.

So, I have to make sure that at every point in time, at most one database-related operation is being executed.

I intend to implement those operations in classes that implement following interface:

```
public interface IPersistenceAction<T> {
    T run(final IPersistenceState aPersistenceState);
}
```

`IPersistenceState` contains references to `java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.Statement`:

```
public interface IPersistenceState {

    void setStatement(final Statement aStatement);

    Statement getStatement();

    void setConnection(final Connection aConnection);

    Connection getConnection();

}
```

The class implementing the `IPersistence` interface should

1. wait until the connection becomes available (i. e. no one else uses it),
2. run a particular set of database-related operations and
3. return the result of the operation.

Note that every database-related operation may return a different type of result, hence we need to specify its type `T` in `IPersistenceAction<T>`

Same thing explained in Java:

```
public class Persistence implements IPersistence {
    private IPersistenceState state; // Contains connection and statement
    private boolean busy = false; // Indicates whether someone uses the object at the moment

    public T runAction(IPersistenceAction<T> action)
    {
        T returnValue = null;

        waitUntilIdle();
        synchronized (this) {
            busy = true;

            returnValue = action.run(state);

            busy = false;

            notifyAll();
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
    ...
}
```

This violates the Java syntax.

But since Java 7, there are closures in the Java language specification.

Can I use them to solve the task of **thread-safe** execution of database operations with **different results** (different `T`s) ?

If yes, can you provide an example?

Comment: "since Java 7, there are closures in the Java language specification". Link? That would be totally new for me. I think you are talking about Java 8.

Comment: Wouldn't this be solvable with a queue of operations and a SingleThreadExecutor? As well as FutureTasks.

Comment: `public <T> T runAction(IPersistenceAction<T> action);` should work ?

Comment: @Pyranja That seems to be the answer. Please submit it as such and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a generic type parameter to a method:

```
public <T> T runAction(IPersistenceAction<T> action);
```

The `<T>` will show the compiler, that T is a type parameter and not a Type itself.

Comment: So in the end, it was a generics issue not a Persistence, or thread-safety... could you edit the question's tags?